# How do I signal test error (not failure) from python unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, python-unittest

I have a test case with a helper method `assertContains(super, sub)`.  The `sub` arguments are  a hard-coded part of the test cases.  In case they're malformed, I would like my test case to abort with an error.

How do I do that?  I have tried

```
def assertContains(super, sub):
    if isinstance(super, foo): ...
    elif isinstance(super, bar): ...
    else: assert False, repr(sub)
```

However, this turns the test into a failure rather than an error.

I could raise some other exception (e.g. `ValueError`), but I want to explicitly state that I'm declaring the test case to be in error.  I could do things like `ErrorInTest = ValueError` and then `raise ErrorInTest(repr(sub))`, but it feels kinda' icky.  I feel there should be a batteries-included way of doing this, but reading the friendly manual didn't suggest anything to me.

Answer (score 1):

There is an `assertRaises()` for aspects in class `TestCase` in which you want to ensure an error is raised by the to-be-tested code.

If you want to raise an error and abort testing that unit at this point (and continue with the next unit test), just raise an uncaught exception; the unit test module will catch it:

```
raise NotImplementedError("malformed sub: %r" % (sub,))
```

I don't think that there is any other API aspect available besides raising errors directly to state that a unit test case results in an error.

```
class PassingTest(unittest.TestCase):
  def runTest(self):
    self.assertTrue(True)

class FailingTest(unittest.TestCase):
  def runTest(self):
    self.assertTrue(False)

class ErrorTest(unittest.TestCase):
  def runTest(self):
    raise NotImplementedError("error")

class PassingTest2(unittest.TestCase):
  def runTest(self):
    self.assertTrue(True)
```

results in:

```
EF..
======================================================================
ERROR: runTest (__main__.ErrorTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./t.py", line 15, in runTest
    raise NotImplementedError("error")
NotImplementedError: error

======================================================================
FAIL: runTest (__main__.FailingTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./t.py", line 11, in runTest
    self.assertTrue(False)
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.002s

FAILED (failures=1, errors=1)
```